# Searching ,watching,Downloading Youtube Videos on Android app using YouTube Data API (v3)

Tags: search, video, youtube, download, playing

i am using Youtube Data API to search videos of you tube in android application but facing problem for getting playlist id,please suggest me how to solve this problem